# How to draw PDF on canvas using skia sharp? in Xamarin Forms

Tags: .net, xamarin

I'm seeking help with SkiaSharp to open a PDF in a canvas view using Xamarin Forms . I'm not familiar with the process and would greatly appreciate any guidance or assistance. If someone here has experience with SkiaSharp and can provide help, I would be very grateful.

Thank you!

I'm seeking help with SkiaSharp to open a PDF in a canvas view using Xamarin Forms .

Comment: https://github.com/DrJohnMelville/Pdf

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to construct a PDF Document with [SKDocument Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.skdocument?view=skiasharp-2.88).

The PDF backend uses `SKDocument` instead of `SKSurface`, since a document must include multiple pages.

```
// create the document
var stream = SKFileWStream.OpenStream("document.pdf");
var document = SKDocument.CreatePdf(stream);

// get the canvas from the page
var canvas = document.BeginPage(256, 256);

// draw on the canvas ...

// end the page and document
document.EndPage();
document.Close();
```

For more information, please check document: [Constructing a PDF Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.skcanvas?view=skiasharp-2.88#constructing-a-pdf-document).